# Why Matcher.group() can't detect repetition?

Tags: java, regex, validation

when i'm using this code to extract the items, regex doesn't detect repetition,thanks for any help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "item1  , item2  , item3 , item4 ";
    String regex = "\\s*([a-z]\\w+)(\\s*,\\s*([a-z]\\w+))*\\s*";
    System.out.println(input.matches(regex));
    Pattern pat = compile(regex);
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(input);
    m.find();
    for (int i = 0; i < m.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(m.group(i));
    }
}
```

Output :

```
true
item1  , item2  , item3 , item4 
item1
 , item4
```

i'm expecting to see :

```
true
item1  , item2  , item3 , item4 
item1
,item2    
,item3
,item4
```

Comment: ie. looking for a match count of 4 instead of 2

Comment: user1072678, please update your question with what you are really wanting to achieve (example input and expected output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doesen't appear Java can do a variable amount of capture variables. It uses the grouping correctly for the match as a whole, but overwrites any capture buffer repetition. This is typical of PCRE style engines. Dot Net can do this very well.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "item1  , item2  , item3 , item4 ";
    String regex = "^\\s*([a-z]\\w+)\\s*,\\s*([a-z]\\w+)\\s*,\\s*([a-z]\\w+)\\s*,\\s*([a-z]\\w+)\\s*$";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(input);
    m.find();
    for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(m.group(i));
    }
    System.out.println("----------");
    regex = "^\\s*([a-z]\\w+)(?:\\s*,\\s*([a-z]\\w+))*\\s*$";
    pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
    m = pat.matcher(input);
    m.find();
    for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(m.group(i));
    }
}
}


Output:

item1
item2
item3
item4
----------
item1
item4
```

Answer (score 3):

And why don't you use `split`?

```
String[] items = input.split(", ");
for (String s : items) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

If I understand correctly, you want to extract the items in the input string. Since they're separated by spaces, commas or a combination of both, you can simply split them by using the regular expression "`,`" as a parameter for the `split` method, and the items will be stored in the returned `String[]`.

Comment: actually that was a part of a string i'm trying to extract from consider the sql command"select col1,col2,col3 from table ....".

Comment: Which part of the String are you trying to  extract? `col1`,`col2`,and `col3`?

Comment: It'll be simpler to pass the above code the substring where the items are, than trying to come up with a regular expression that covers the whole range of possible sql commands. The substring would be easy to find with `indexOf`, it's in between the "select" and the "from" parts

Comment: 1.col1, col2, col3
2.table_name
if there a where statement "where col1 > 3"
3.condition 
i've already made a regex to validate the input statement and it worked

Comment: @ÓscarLópez what about validating the command anyway in my assignment i'm dealing with few sql statements

Comment: It depends on how complex that command is; for the general case, the syntactical validation of a SQL command with a regular expression is not at all trivial, it'd be a better idea to use a parser with a well-defined grammar for SQL

Comment: user1072678, I still don't follow. Your example string do not contains `1.col1`. Please be more specific, put effort into making a question which can be answered without playing guessing games.

Comment: sorry i was trying to make a list

Answer (score 2):

The repetition part of the regex is not within the captured group. Try this:

```
String regex = "\\s*([a-z]\\w+)((?:\\s*,\\s*([a-z]\\w+))*)\\s*";
```

Comment: sorry it didn't work
     <pre> item1, item2, item3
     item1
     , item2, item3<code>

Comment: Looks like you want a regex which returns a variable number of groups, each with one item. Regexes don't work that way and you should instead split as recommended by Óscar López.

Answer (score 0):

[Matcher.find](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method returns a `boolean` indicating if there is a match. You should have an outer loop checking it:

```
while (m.find()) {
  for (int i = 0; i < m.groupCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println(m.group(i));
  }
}
```

This can correctly handle both zero matches and multiple matches cases.

Reference: [Lesson: Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html)

Comment: Just to be clear. If your goal here is to extract the items with two or more characters starting with a lower case letter, you can combine the outer loop with a `([a-z]\\w+)` regex. I think it is way simpler than coming up with a regex that discards comma and empty spaces.